# How to retain the variable states in a chrome extension made with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using React JS to create a chrome extension, this extension use the Chrome API to start the network recording and create a .HAR file, the problem is... I have a button to start that recording but if if I click elsewhere on the page the popup closes, so when I open it again and click the button to stop the recording, the previous recording start will have disappeared, this is my files, I was trying with webpack to become all the jsx file into a js file to put inside the manifest in the "Background" but it does not work,this is my files structure now:
[image]

And the code in the recordPage.jsx which is the code in charge to manage the record is (I reallr appreciate any contribution, please):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { HARBuilder } from "./model/har";
import { Stats, StatsBuilder } from "./model/stats";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSignOut } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { logout } from "./reducers/authSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
/*global chrome*/

const RecordPage = () => {
  var [isRecording] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  var tabs = {};
  var version = "1.0";

  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['tabs'], function (result) {
      const tabs = result.tabs;
      isRecording = !isRecording;
      if (tabs?.[activeInfo.tabId]) {
        chrome.action.setTitle({ tabId: activeInfo.tabId, title: 'Click to stop record network requests.' });
      } else {
        chrome.action.setTitle({ tabId: activeInfo.tabId, title: 'Click to start record network requests.' });
      }
    });
  });

  const refactorBtn = (tab) => {
    isRecording = !isRecording;
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, windowType: "normal", currentWindow: true }, function (d) { tab = d[0] })
    chrome.storage.local.get(['tabs'], async function (result) {
      let newTabs = result.tabs;

      if (newTabs?.[tab.id]) {
        chrome.debugger.detach({ tabId: tab.id });
        chrome.action.setTitle({ tabId: tab.id, title: 'Click to start record network requests.' });
        try {
          const fileName = new URL(tab.url).host;
          chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
              target: { tabId: tab.id },
              args: [encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(new HARBuilder().create([tabs[tab.id]], fileName))), `${fileName}.har`],
              function: generateHARFile,
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        newTabs[tab.id] = undefined;
        await writeTabObject(newTabs);
        console.log(`Action clicked: Tab ${tab.id} now unregistered.`);
      } else {

        //initialize the prop
        if (!newTabs) {
          newTabs = {};
        }

        let stats = new Stats();
        tabs[tab.id] = stats;
        newTabs[tab.id] = stats;
        await writeTabObject(newTabs);

        chrome.action.setTitle({ tabId: tab.id, title: 'Click to stop record network requests.' });
        chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tab.id }, version, onAttach.bind(null, tab.id));
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tab.id }, "Network.enable");

        chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(async (debuggeeId, method, params) => {

          StatsBuilder.processEvent(stats, { method, params });
          tabs[tab.id] = stats;
          if (method === "Network.loadingFinished") {
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tab.id }, "Network.getResponseBody", { requestId: params.requestId }, (responseBodyParams) => {
              if (responseBodyParams) {
                const { body, base64Encoded } = responseBodyParams;
                StatsBuilder.processEvent(stats, {
                  method: 'Network.getResponseBody', params: {
                    requestId: params.requestId,
                    body,
                    base64Encoded
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  function generateHARFile(encodedString, fileName) {
    /*const file = new File([encodedString], fileName, {
      type: "application/json"
    });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    try {
      const response = fetch("http://localhost:8081/BlobAPI", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }*/
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json,' + encodedString);
    element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }

  function onAttach(tabId) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
  }

  function readTabObject() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.get(['tabs'], function (result) {
        if (result['tabs']) {
          resolve(result['tabs']);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  function writeTabObject(tabs) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.set({ tabs }, function (result) {
        resolve(tabs);
      });
    });
  }

  function readResponseBody(tabId, requestId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Network.getResponseBody", { requestId }, (responseBody) => {
        resolve(responseBody);
      });
    });
  }

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-96 flex flex-col justify-center bg-white rounded-lg">
      <button
        className="btn btn-circle bg-varxen-secundaryGray border-varxen-secundaryGray ml-2 mt-2"
        onClick={logoutHandler}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOut} size="xs" />
      </button>
      <div className="flex justify-center mt-3">
        <h1 className="text-xl text-black font-bold">Record your session</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center m-t">
        {!isRecording && (
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline btn-success m-3"
            onClick={refactorBtn}
          >
            Start record
          </button>
        )}
        {isRecording && (
          <button
            className="btn btn-outline btn-error m-3"
            onClick={refactorBtn}
          >
            End record
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};

export default RecordPage;
```